# Meaning of "Angeln von Unbefugten"

Tags: meaning, preposition

From the *Hohlspiegel* column of Der Spiegel, which is intended for funny/interesting sentences from other sources:

> Schild an einem Fischweiher in Saarbrücken-Ensheim:
>
> Baden, Verunreinigen, Einlassen von Hunden, Angeln von Unbefugten ist verboten!

I guess the reason this is funny is the notion of unauthorized people being fished (instead of them doing the fishing.) In that sense, "Angeln von Unbefugten" is ambiguous. How can we make it clear? Would it be "Angeln **für** Unbefugten"?

Comment: You could obfuscate even more by writing _„Angeln von Unbefugten verboten!“_ – Unauthorized persons must not fish? Unauthorized persons must not be fished for? Unauthorized persons forbade to fish? Fishing rods of unauthorized persons are forbidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: You are right. The reason this is funny is the notion of unauthorized people being fished (instead of them doing the fishing.)

Beside the other already posted possibilities I would also use:

> Angeln durch Unbefugte ist verboten!

or you could use

> unbefugtes Angeln ist verboten!

A remark from my subjective feeling:

To fish in Germany you need two things: an official license ([Fischereischein or Angelschein](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischereischein)) and a permission to fish in this specific river/lake.

If you use `widerrechtlich` I think there is a missing `Fischereischein`, with `unbefugt` I think, you have the Fischereischein, but not the permission to fish here. So in this case I would prefer `unbefugt`, because the owner of the tarn wants to protect his own rights.

But that's my subjective view (I'm no fisher and no lawywer).

Answer (score 2):

"Angeln für Unbefugte verboten." or "Angeln ist Unbefugten verboten." would both be very clear and a correct sentence. However, this cannot be inserted in the accumulation. You would have to change it into "widerrechtliches Angeln", as rogermue suggested.

Result: "Baden, Verunreinigen, Einlassen von Hunden ( , / und) widerrechtliches Angeln ist verboten."

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

> Angeln verboten

or

> widerrechtliches Angeln verboten.

Answer (score 1):

"Angeln durch Unbefugte" would work as well.